# Android AutoCompeleteTextView not gives proper result

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am new in android and use Custom AutoCompleteTextView, here is code form AutoCompleteText

```
<com.xxxxxxxx.supports.CustomAutoComplete
            android:id="@+id/edit_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/search_products_colors_more"
            android:imeActionId="123456"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/light_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14sp" />
```

[This is list comes when I search some thing over server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGVY7.png)
and [When I clicked on first item Steel Grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl4ko.png) It shows like this.

I am not able to figure out the error, Sometime it comes and sometime not.
Please help.

Edit Update:

```
public class CustomAutoComplete extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

private static final int MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED = 100;
private static final int DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY = 750;

private int mAutoCompleteDelay = DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY;
private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        CustomAutoComplete.super.performFiltering((CharSequence) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
    }
};

public CustomAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setLoadingIndicator(ProgressBar progressBar) {
    mLoadingIndicator = progressBar;
}

public void setAutoCompleteDelay(int autoCompleteDelay) {
    mAutoCompleteDelay = autoCompleteDelay;
}

@Override
protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, text), mAutoCompleteDelay);
}

@Override
public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    super.onFilterComplete(count);
}
```

}

Model Class below here

```
public class SearchResults {

private String suggetions, suggetionId;

public SearchResults(String suggetions, String suggetionId) {

    this.suggetions = suggetions;
    this.suggetionId = suggetionId;
}

public String getSuggetions() {
    return suggetions;
}

public String getSuggetionId() {
    return suggetionId;
}

public void setSuggetionId(String suggetionId) {
    this.suggetionId = suggetionId;
}}
```

Code in fragment class

```
 public CustomAutoComplete edit_search;
 edit_search.setThreshold(3);
    edit_search.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), resultList, SearchItems.this)); // 'this' is Activity instance
    edit_search.setLoadingIndicator(progress_search);

    edit_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            try {
                getPerspective().closeKeyboard();
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    if (resultList.size() != 0) {
                        if (edit_search.getText().length() > 2) {
                            String text = resultList.get(0).getSuggetions();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Text : " + text);
                            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("No Results!")) {
                                edit_search.dismissDropDown();
                                layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                layout_mic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                layout_mic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                getPerspective().openProdcuctList("0", text.trim());
                            }
                        } else if (edit_search.getText().length() < 3 && edit_search.getText().length() > 0) {
                            getPerspective().showMessage("Enter minimum three characters!");
                        } else if (edit_search.getText().length() <= 0) {
                            getPerspective().showMessage("Please enter your search query!");
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (edit_search.getText().length() == 0) {
                layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layout_mic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Now Adapter class code is

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


public Context context;
private List<SearchResults> resultsList;
SearchItems searchItems;
Perspective perspective;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public Perspective getPerspective() {
    if (perspective == null)
        perspective = (Perspective) context;
    return perspective;
}

public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<SearchResults> resultsList, SearchItems searchItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.resultsList = resultsList;
    this.searchItems = searchItems;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resultsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_result_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txt_item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txt_item_name.setText(resultsList.get(position).getSuggetions());

    viewHolder.txt_item_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String query = resultsList.get(position).getSuggetions();
            Log.e("Search","Query : "+query);
           // searchItems.edit_search.setText(query);

            if (!query.equals("No Results!")) {
                getPerspective().closeKeyboard();
                searchItems.edit_search.dismissDropDown();
                getPerspective().openProdcuctList("0", query);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_item_name;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                List<SearchResults> listSuggs = findSuggastions(context, constraint.toString());
                filterResults.values = listSuggs;
                filterResults.count = listSuggs.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                resultsList = (List<SearchResults>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}

private List<SearchResults> findSuggastions(Context context, String title) {
    resultsList.clear();
    return resultsList = getSearchResults(title);
}

private List<SearchResults> getSearchResults(final String keyword) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_top_search";
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            APIs.url_api_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                Log.e("SearchAdapter", "Response : " + response);
                JSONArray object = new JSONArray(response);

                //resultsList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject(i);
                    String prod_id = jsonObject.getString("product_id");
                    String prod_nam = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    SearchResults searchSuggs = new SearchResults(prod_nam, prod_id);
                    resultsList.add(searchSuggs);
                }
                if (resultsList.size() == 1) {
                    String prod_nam = resultsList.get(0).getSuggetions();
                    if (prod_nam.equalsIgnoreCase("No Results!")) {
                        searchItems.edit_search.dismissDropDown();
                        searchItems.layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        searchItems.layout_mic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        searchItems.layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        searchItems.layout_mic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }else {
                    getPerspective().closeKeyboard();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("keyword", keyword);
            return params;
        }
    };
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError arg0) throws VolleyError {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    strReq.setShouldCache(false);
    Controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    return resultsList;
}
```

}

I have updated code,

Comment: add the adapter and bean class that you have used

Comment: @MJM I have update question add all detail you require. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Override toString methods and return data that you want to display.

```
 public class SearchResults {

    private String suggetions, suggetionId;

    public SearchResults(String suggetions, String suggetionId) {

        this.suggetions = suggetions;
        this.suggetionId = suggetionId;
    }

    public String getSuggetions() {
        return suggetions;
    }

    public String getSuggetionId() {
        return suggetionId;
    }

    public void setSuggetionId(String suggetionId) {
        this.suggetionId = suggetionId;
    }

     @Override
        public final String toString()
        {
    return suggetions;
    }
    }
```